# Precision loss if converting from XMLGregorianCalendar to java.util.Date

Tags: java, xml, date

I have written a test to convert a XMLGregorianCalendar date to a java.util.Date and back. My start xml date has the string value "2015-02-03T11:32:41.000755" but after it`s converted back from java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar the string value is "2015-02-03T11:32:41.000". Has anyone an idea to change the code so that the last 3 digits of the xml date can be preserved?

Thanks,
Erik

Here is the code:

```
public class XMLCalendarTest {

    @Test
    public void testDateFormats() {

        try {
            // DateTime (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS)
            final String dateTimeText = "2015-02-03T11:32:41.000755";
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDateTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateTimeText);
            Assert.assertEquals(dateTimeText, xmlDateTime.toXMLFormat());

            // after converting from Date the XML date is "2015-02-03T11:32:41.000" --> why?
            Assert.assertEquals(dateTimeText, createXMLDateTime(createDate(xmlDateTime)));

        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private XMLGregorianCalendar createXMLDateTime(final Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        if (date == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();

        c.setTime(date);

         final XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
         xmlCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);

         return xmlCalendar;

    }

    private static Date createDate(final XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar) {
        if (xmlCalendar != null) {
            return xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) only maintains millisecond precision.

The [java.sql.TimeStamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) has nanosecond precision.

I do not see an automated way to convert between the XMLGregorianCalendar and a TimeStamp, but the [getFractionalSeconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getFractionalSecond--) should provide access to the level of precision you desire.